# Have two steamworks accounts?

Tags: steam

I am finishing my game project and I already have my steamworks registration, I am just fine-tuning details and preparing marketing for the start.

But I look a little short of cash, I would like to invest more in marketing, when I heard this, a friend recommended that I sell some educational games that I had done a while ago (type "dora the explorer") but I don't want to publish them in my account , since my current project is a game of gore, blood, violence etc. I don't think it's right that they are "together", can I generate a new steamworks account to publish my other games?

I have not found anything in the document confirming that yes or no

Answer (score 2):

I have never worked on steam but after few searches i found this on Quora:

**Quote from ["Adam Henley"](https://www.quora.com/profile/Adam-Henley)**

" The advice on Steam’s FAQ:

**Should I create a new Steam account to post with?**

This will depend on your situation. If your Steam account is already associated with a Steamworks partner and your submission is for that partner, then you should continue to use that Steam account. If you are a member of an existing Steamworks partner but wish to post a submission that will not be part of that Steamworks partner, then please create a new Steam account before you post.

If you represent a team of individuals or a company, you may find it beneficial to create a new Steam account to represent your team or company rather than using your personal account to post.

> Src: [Steam Workshop :: Greenlight FAQs](https://steamcommunity.com/games/593110/announcements/detail/558846854614253751#developers)

I can see benefits of creating a separate account, including but not limited to (other benefits available):

- You may want to publish as a brand to look more professional
- You may want to maintain the privacy of your existing Steam account
- A VAC ban or bad feedback from a trade on your personal profile might look bad (even if they have innocent explanations).

> [Link To Quroa Post](https://www.quora.com/Should-I-create-a-separate-Steam-account-for-my-game-development-projects)

**Note:** I don't have any experience with steam And I am not sure how legit is the above answer. I am just trying to help if i am able.